# Realistic Futuristic Spaceship Design Possibilities

Tags: spaceships

What would a realistic futuristic spaceship design be like? What properties must it have? What would be illogical to have?

My story is set about, say 100 years from now

Comment: Welcome to Worldbuiding! (I don't know where the usual people who do this went...) Your question is a bit too open ended, asking us to design a spaceship for you. You've also combined a couple questions together with no requirements of specifications. I've you've already designed a spaceship, post it up and give us a description and someone can probably help you nail down the design, but we can't really design a spaceship for you just because you want it. Otherwise, you will need to do some more research and narrow down your design ideas before we can help.

Comment: @Shadowzee, there are no "usual people who do this" ;) it's the community, and you are community, too

Comment: For 100 years from now, you can just look at the roadmap and Concepts of SpaceX, Blue Origin, NASA and the likes and extrapolate from there.

Comment: In addition to the excellent comments so far, I'll add:
Absent miraculous new developments in electrostatic magnetic field generation leading to hyper-dense fields of force, if your ship(s) are designed for more than small in-system movement, they will need to be able to withstand significant dust impacts, minor micro-meteoriod impacts, a wide range of radiative exposures, and have enough reactant aboard for extended maneuvers or some kind of reactionless drive (EM drive et al) or to be able to re-fuel in transit.
Those design constraints, on top of human life support, drive your design.

Comment: Everything you need and more is available at this website: http://www.projectrho.com/public_html/rocket/ . It is my favorite web resource.

Answer (score 1):

Everything depends on what technology they have and what the aim of your story is

If they don't have artificial gravity, ships are more likely to have rings and/or cylinders so centrifugal force gives the crew something like gravity to make life easier.

Are they travelling between stars? Do they have FTL or are they generational ships? Do they have cyrogentics? Do they have AI? Are they at war or at risk of pirates or hostile aliens? Do they use rockets, solar sails, orion drives or warp drives?

Everything affects the design of the ship. Generational ships will be huge flying cities. FTL ships will be smaller and faster. AI run ship may have no crew at all or keep crew frozen until needed. An orion drive requires a massive shock absorber plate to contain the nuclear explosions. A warp drive may require the engine to be located some distance from the crew.

Once you work out your tech, the ship will design itself.

Comment: This sounds like a nice comment asking more details...